# Youtube live streaming API - list watching users

Tags: c#, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I wanted to make my own chatbot for livestreaming and I'm struggling with the loyalty system. I wanted to reward users for watching the stream. But I'm unable to list all users that are watching the livestream using data/livestream API. I can list moderators, messages or concurrent viewers (just a number). But I would need list of names/ids/some identification so I can assign rewards. Is it possible to do with youtube API?

I saw some working loyalty system bots (like FussBot) but they were on YouTube Gaming, this is regular livestream. Is it possible to do it on Youtube? I wasn't able to find it in google documentation.

Code below is working snippet how to get credentials and service to run some queries.

```
UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly },
    "user",
    CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString()));
}

var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "bot name"
});
```